# RxJava2 could not find Func0

Tags: android, rx-java

RxJava 2 almost released and I want to migrate from RX 1.2.0 to 2.0.0, But I have noticed that there is no Func0 interface in RxJava 2.

What developers should use instead of Func0 in RxJava 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From their elaboration on [what's changed between RxJava 1.x and 2.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0):

> We followed the naming convention of Java 8 by defining
>   `io.reactivex.functions.Function` and `io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction`,
>   plus renaming `Func3` - `Func9` into `Function3` - `Function9` respectively.
>   The `FuncN` is replaced by the `Function<Object[], R>` type declaration.
>
> In addition, operators requiring a predicate no longer use `Func1<T,
>   Boolean>` but have a separate, primitive-returning type of `Predicate<T>`
>   (allows better inlining due to no autoboxing).
>
> The `io.reactivex.functions.Functions` utility class offers common
>   function sources and conversions to `Function<Object[], R>`.

Comment: But
`io.reactivex.functions.Function` is `rx.functions.Func1`
and
`io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction` is `rx.functions.Func2`
So there is no equivalent to Func0?

Answer (score 17):

RxJava2 use Callable interface from JDK (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

Example with Observable.defer (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#defer(java.util.concurrent.Callable) )

```
Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<MyObject>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<MyObject> call() throws Exception {
        return Observable.just(new MyObject());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

RxJava2 uses `java.util.concurrent.Callable` from java7 instead of `Func0`